# 415Unsupported Media Type in endpoint generated by openapi 3.0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, postman, openapi

I've generated endpoint using openapi 3.0 that consumes form data. No idea what could have I done wrong, since its all generated and in past I've been able to upload file like this. The difference is that now I have multiple fields other than file.

```
paths:
  /movie:
    post:
      operationId: createMovie
      description: creates movie
      requestBody:
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/MovieRequest'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: ''
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Movie'
```

Movie request component:

```
MovieRequest:
      type: object
      properties:
        title:
          type: string
        description:
          type: string
        director:
          type: string
        length:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        category:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Category'
        ageCategory:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/AgeCategory'
        poster:
          type: string
          format: binary
        trailerLink:
          type: string
        shortDescription:
          type: string
```

Generated controller:

```
 @ApiOperation(value = "", nickname = "createMovie", notes = "creates movie", response = MovieModelApi.class, tags={  })
    @ApiResponses(value = { 
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "", response = MovieModelApi.class) })
    @RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        value = "/movie",
        produces = { "application/json" },
        consumes = { "multipart/form-data" }
    )
    default ResponseEntity<MovieModelApi> createMovie(@ApiParam(value = "") @Valid @RequestPart(value = "title", required = false) String title,@ApiParam(value = "") @Valid @RequestPart(value = "description", required = false) String description,@ApiParam(value = "") @Valid @RequestPart(value = "director", required = false) String director,@ApiParam(value = "", allowableValues = "HORROR") @Valid @RequestPart(value = "category", required = false) CategoryModelApi category,@ApiParam(value = "", allowableValues = "PG13") @Valid @RequestPart(value = "ageCategory", required = false) AgeCategoryModelApi ageCategory,@ApiParam(value = "") @Valid @RequestPart(value = "poster", required = false) MultipartFile poster) {
        getRequest().ifPresent(request -> {
            for (MediaType mediaType: MediaType.parseMediaTypes(request.getHeader("Accept"))) {
                if (mediaType.isCompatibleWith(MediaType.valueOf("application/json"))) {
                    String exampleString = "{ \"director\" : \"director\", \"isEnabled\" : true, \"description\" : \"description\", \"id\" : 5, \"title\" : \"title\", \"poster\" : \"poster\" }";
                    ApiUtil.setExampleResponse(request, "application/json", exampleString);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);

    }
```

After importing the yaml to postman I send request:
[image: Postman request]

That contains headers:
[image: Headers]

But I get 415 unsupported media error

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type indicates that the server is refusing to accept the request because the payload format is not supported. The format problem may be related to the Content-Type or Content-Encoding specified in the request, or as a result of direct validation of the data.